# Why we say Dependency Injection is a Java Spring framework feature, instead of Java language feature?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

1. I am new to Java Spring framework. In some articles, they say that Spring framework has the Dependency Injection. Why don't we say Java language has Dependency Injection feature since Spring is based on Java? This kind of question confused me for some time. Besides Java and Spring, I also have this question for ASP.NET MVC and C#.
2. The following is Spring Dependency Injection code example. If I create a small program in Java, It will also work, right?

**Spring:**

```
package com.example.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class DatabaseAccountService implements AccountService {

    private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseAccountService(RiskAssessor riskAssessor) {
        this.riskAssessor = riskAssessor;
    }

    // ...

}
```

**Java:**

```
public class DatabaseAccountService implements AccountService {

    private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor;

    public DatabaseAccountService(RiskAssessor riskAssessor) {
        this.riskAssessor = riskAssessor;
    }

    // ...

}
```

**Update (This is where I confused): In pure Java, I thought If class A is dependent on class B. After we create class A and B, we only need to go to Class A, then do 'public A(B b)'. Besides this, what others we should do?**

Comment: Spring is a _tool_ that allows applying the [Dependency Injection](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) _pattern_. It's not so much that Java has DI, but rather that DI is a _pattern for OOP languages. You can practice DI without a tool, which is called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Comment: @Steven Is there any OOP languages do not support DI pattern?

Comment: @Steven In my second question, Java version code will also work, right?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Whether your second example will work in combination with String is unclear to me (I'm not familiar with Spring), but it is an example of correctly applied DI.

Comment: @Steven "second example will work in combination with String" No, I mean, my Java version code is separate with Spring, so, it is pure Java, will it work?

Comment: As I said, the second example applies DI and Constructor Injection in particular. You will have to define "will it work" before I can answer that, but it seems valid Java and DI is applied correctly. You might want to pick up a [good book](https://manning.com/seemann2/) about DI.

Comment: DI is all about how you organise your code, no "support" is necessary from the language, nor any special libraries. All Spring does is make DI easier than it would be to do by hand. (It also comes with its own set of problems, which is why some people choose not to use Spring while still keeping DI.)

Comment: @biziclop When you say "than it would be to do by hand" What else we need to do if we do not use Spring? Can you check the Update in my post? Thank you.

Comment: There's no magic to it, you just make sure that your business classes receive their dependent objects as parameters rather than instantiating them directly. (Like you did in your example.) If you do this everywhere, you'll realise you still need a bit that does nothing but instantiate your dependent objects and "injects" them on startup. This last step is the "manual" part of DI that Spring replaces with its automated version via auto-wiring. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect your update. With many helpful comments I see here, confusion will hopefully disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Because in Spring *automated* dependency injection is ready to use feature. In plain java, you have to find or create your dependency yourself and then inject it into dependee.

Notice word automated. Strictly speaking, yes, dependency injection is already present in plain Java,
but authors surely ment the automatic one.

2) Your code will work, but you will have to find or create an instance of RiskAssessor yourself, and if you are creating it (that is Spring didn't do it for you), you will have to give it all its dependencies as well and only then construct then DatabaseAccoutService.

If dependencies of DatabaseAccountService depend on a lot of dependencies themself, you will appreaciate the Spring doing the work for you. Hopefully :)

---ad your update:
Yes, that's pretty much it. Thanks to such constructor A(B b) dependency b gets injected into instance of class A. Just don't forget, you will want to actually call your constructor A with instance of class B as parameter somewhere. 
And thats where you will need to have instance of B to pass it as parameter. And you will have to create it as well and with that whatever it needs to be created.
That's why many use DI frameworks to gather the dependecies and inject them.

Comment: "In plain java, you have to find or create your dependency yourself and then inject it into dependee" How to do it? I think I only need to define a new class for RiskAssessor, then in my DatabaseAccountService  class, I can directly use public DatabaseAccountService(RiskAssessor riskAssessor), this will work?

Comment: You are probably already doing it on many places. Like this: new DatabaseAccountService (someRiskAssessorInstance);  From exactly where you will call DAS constructor doesn't matter. The dependency (someRiskAssessorInstance) gets injected into the instance of DatabaseAccountService.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because you have other frameworks that offer dependency injection other than Spring. Java is a general purpose language, and many frameworks were built to fulfill certain "jobs" and requirements, to make them easier to complete.

Imagine you need to drill a hole in a wall using a drill. Are you going to build your own drill every time you need a hole, or are you going to reuse the same drill, just provide the power for it's use?
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

2. When you instantiate your DataBaseAccountService without dependency inejction, your RiskAssessor can be any instance of the class. But, when you have DI, basically the framework will make sure that the proper (providing there's no ambiguity) instance bean is assigned to the field. It makes sure that you have to define your bean at your configuration class, give it certain properties, and then use the same bean with the same properties and capabilities throughout your application and not reinstantiate it every time you need it.

Comment: Look like your answer is why we need Dependency Injection, but my question is not asking why we need DI.

Comment: @QuestionContributor Spring framework is a lot more than just a DI provider. Any framework you use will offer it to you. If you still are having issues with your question `Why don't we say Java language has Dependency Injection feature since Spring is based on Java? ` - I could say: Java language has the ability for you to build your own DI, but why when you have Spring (or other DI capable frameworks). Spring is based on Java, same way a drill is based on a number of components which will provide you with the ability to drill a hole. Do you still want to build your own drill? Maybe.

Comment: "Java language has the ability for you to build your own DI" This is where I am confused. Why did you say that we need to build your own DI? I thought If class A is dependent on class B. After we create class A and B, we only need to go to Class A, then do 'public A(B b)'. Besides this, what others we should do? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean to say you "need", only that you "can" :D 

And for the dependent classes: just to clarify this for you, you can also inject through fields and not just by constructors (even though constructor injection is 'smarter', but let's ignore that for now).
Lets say your class A has a private field B and it is dependent on it. You don't have to inject it through the constructor, you can simply say @Autowired on the private field B dependencyB; and once you instantiate A, dependencyB will automatically be initialized. With your own implementation, you would have to say setB(dependB)..

Comment: I know what you mentioned. But could you directly answer my this question ''I thought If class A is dependent on class B. After we create class A and B, we only need to go to Class A, then do 'public A(B b)'. Besides this, what others we should do?" I want to know what else I should do in Pure Java instead of Spring in order to have DI work. Sorry for my question but I want to know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "Besides this what other should we do"?
When you create class A, you need to MAKE SURE that B is instantiated and passed through the constructor so A has the dependency satisfied. 
Meaning, you have to say B b = new B(); Then A a = new A(b); every time you make an instance of A.
Other than instantiating it every time, you could make B a singleton and always pass the same instance...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151145/discussion-between-ognjen-misic-and-questioncontributor).